# Java refresh table(jstl - c:out) by ajax request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, html-table, jstl

Java using ajax:

[image]

Java without ajax:

[image]

I have a table with some address data which retrieved from SQL database query:

```
<div id="address_table_container">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="addresstable">
    <tr>
        <td class="mytd">Name</td>
        <td class="mytd">Type</td>
        <td class="mytd">Code 4.0</td>
        <td class="mytd">PostalCode</td>
        <td class="mytd">OKTMO</td>
        <td class="mytd">OKATO</td>
        <td class="mytd">Status</td>
    </tr>
<c:forEach var="address" items="${addresses}">
    <tr>
        <td class="mytd"><c:out value="${address.formalname}"></c:out>  </td>
        <td class="mytd"><c:out value="${address.shortname}"></c:out></td>
        <td class="mytd"><c:out value="${address.code}"></c:out></td>
        <td class="mytd"><c:out value="${address.postalcode}"></c:out></td>
        <td class="mytd"><c:out value="${address.oktmo}"></c:out></td>
        <td class="mytd"><c:out value="${address.okato}"></c:out></td>
        <td class="mytd"><c:out value="${address.actstatus}"></c:out></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</div>
```

Input query form with submit button:

```
<form name='f' id='theForm' action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' method='POST'>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name='formalname' placeholder="search"  id="search" placeholder="search" onkeyup="doOn(this);"/>
<input id="somebutton" name="submit" type="submit" value="Query" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
```

ajax request for updating table without updating whole page

```
var frm = $('#theForm');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
$.ajax({
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: frm.serialize(),
    success: function(data){
          $("#address_table_container").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ #addresstable");          
    }
});

ev.preventDefault();
});
```

java controller get data from DB(based on formalname)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showAddresses(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "formalname", required = false) String getaddress,
        @RequestParam(value = "queryall", required = false) String queryall) {

    ArrayList<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    ...
    addresses.addAll(...);
    ...
    model.addAttribute("addresses", addresses);
    ...
    return "home";
    }
```

So if I don't use ajax my table refreshes fine after I make a query, but if I use ajax to update just my table(#addresstable) the table doesn't update, but ajax request to Java controller works. So I have to update table without refresh whole page.

-----Update---

```
$("#address_table_container").html(data);
```

if I paste this in ajax request. It updates data fine. But it updated whole page into div. So how can i get only table data?

Comment: "/" and home here the same

Comment: model.addAttribute("addresses", addresses) goes to home.jsp ('path -/') to <c:forEach var="address" items="${addresses}">

Comment: In java? table just one thing i have to update. So i have to update exact tag by reference using ajax.

Comment: the page rendered for the first time and the page returned by ajax are same?

Comment: Yes. Table updated by input search user request on the same page.

Comment: put a screenshot of the page after ajax call

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it in a "Create a banking app" assignment

In 'dashboard.jsp' I have a table that displays the current users accounts

```
<div id="account-list">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Account #</td>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>Balance</td>
                <td>Rate (%)</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${user.getAccounts()}" var="acct">
                <tr onclick="updateAcctView(${acct.getId()});">
                    <td>${acct.getAccountNumber()}</td>
                    <td>${acct.getAccountType().getTypeName()}</td>
                    <td>${acct.getBalance()}</td>
                    <td>${acct.getRate()}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>            
</div>
```

And another to show selected account's details

```
<div id="account-view">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account #</th>
                <th>Acct Type</th>
                <th>Balance</th>
                <th>Rate (%)</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>${account.getAccountNumber()}</td>
                <td>${account.getAccountType().getTypeName()}</td>
                <td>${account.getBalance()}</td>
                <td>${account.getRate()}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Clicking an account in 'account-list' calls 'updateAcctView(${acct.getId()});' which updates the table in 'account-view'.  I have the function at the bottom of 'dashboard.jsp' just before the closing 'body' tag

```
<script>
    function updateAcctView($val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",  
            url: "/acctView/" + $val,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#account-view").html( response );
            }
        });
    }               
</script>
```

This sends a GET request to /acctView/{[clicked account id]} and replaces the contents of 'account-view' with the response

In my controller I have

```
@GetMapping("/acctView/{id}")
public String acctView(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Optional<Account> oA = service.findAccountById(id);
    if (oA.isPresent()) {
        model.addAttribute("account ", (Account)oA.get());
    }
    return "/dashboard/acctView.jsp";
}
```

This returns 'acctView.jsp' with the selected account in the model attribute 'account'

And 'acctView.jsp' for just the table

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account #</th>
                    <th>Acct Type</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                    <th>Rate (%)</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>${account.getAccountNumber()}</td>
                    <td>${account.getAccountType().getTypeName()}</td>
                    <td>${account.getBalance()}</td>
                    <td>${account.getRate()}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```